# Perl Image::Magick Method to create a drop shadow (non command line)

Tags: perl, imagemagick, shadow

I found this PHP version that seems to be the result I need.

```
    <?php

try
{

    /*** a new Imagick object ***/
    $im = new Imagick('images/spork.jpg');

    /*** set the image format to png ***/
    $im->setImageFormat('png');

    /*** an object for the drop shadow ***/
    $shadow = $im->clone();

    /*** an object for the drop shadow ***/
    $drop_shadow = $im->clone();

    /*** set shadow color to black ***/
    $drop_shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) );

    /*** Create the shadow ***/
    $drop_shadow->shadowImage( 80, 3, 5, 5 );

    /*** stick them together ***/
    $drop_shadow->compositeImage( $im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 );

    /*** write image to disk ***/
    $drop_shadow->writeImage( '/tmp/dropshadow.png' );

    echo 'Wrote Image';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessasge();
}
?>
```

(Tried to post image, would not let me.)
Example here: [spork with drop shadow](http://www.phpro.org/images/dropshadow.png)

Now, I have achieved results I need using this in Perl (with another image):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my imageurl='http://nonprofit.org/images/someimage.jpg';
my $contact='email@email.org';
system("montage $imageurl -geometry 476x356  -background '#F7F7F7' -quality 90 -fill '#ffffff' -shadow \ -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -gravity SouthWest -font Candice -pointsize 14  -annotate +2+1 '$contact' \ -stroke none -fill white -gravity SouthWest -font Candice -pointsize 14  -annotate +2+2 '$contact' \ -gravity center $new");

system("montage $new -geometry 480x360  -background '#F7F7F7' -quality 90 -fill '#F7F7F7' $new");
```

Which gives me a nice drop shadowed aspect ratio(ed) image centered in a 480x360 box/canvas that matches the pages bgcolor f7f7f7.

Now, I desire to do this without using system method.

So, I tried this:

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl -w
        use Image::Resize;
        use Image::Magick;
        use strict;
        my imageurl='http://nonprofit.org/images/someimage.jpg';
        my $contact='email@email.org';
        my $ibig = Image::Magick->new;
        $ibig->Read("$imageurl");
        $ibig->Resize(geometry=>'476x356');
        $ibig->Montage(geometry=>'476x356',
          background=>'#F7F7F7',
          quality=>90,gravity=>'center',
          shadow=>80x4+4+4); 
    #tried shadow=>'true'  and '1' and many other variations.
     $ibig->Annotate(text=>$contact,
          x=>2,y=>1,
          font=>'Candice',
          pointsize=>14,
          stroke=>'#000C',
          strokewidth=>2,
          gravity=>'SouthWest');

    $ibig->Annotate(text=>$contact,
          x=>2,y=>2,
          font=>'Candice',
          pointsize=>14,
          fill=>'#ffffff',
          stroke=>'none',
          gravity=>'SouthWest');

     $ibig->Montage(geometry=>'480x360',
          background=>'#F7F7F7',
          quality=>90,
          fill=>'#F7F7F7');

$ibig->Write("$new");
```

Which does not work. The annotate works but, no drop shadow and the image usually ends up 479x360.

The system method works flawlessly but, I really want to learn how to do this with my Image::Magick example.

I spent two days researching this and reading man.

When I can't figure it out, I come to stackoverflow and ALWAYS get a solution!

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry about formatting issues.. I tried to clean it up.)

Comment: “When I can't figure it out, I come to stackoverflow and ALWAYS get a solution!”  So why do you have only a reputation of 1?

Comment: Dunno. Been coming here for a year. Perhaps because I always delete my cookies at the end of the day? Don't care about rep anyhow, not here for that. Will that effect my ability to get answers? Concerns me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Montage()` returns a new image.
Try:

```
$ibig = $ibig->Montage(...)
```

The [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#montage) doesn't explicitly mention this, unfortunately, but there are some examples on this page which show this.

Comment: Can't locate object method "Write" via package "Exception 410: unrecognized attribute `quality' @ Magick.xs/XS_Image__Magick_Montage/9797" (perhaps you forgot to load "Exception 410: But, what about shadow syntax?

Comment: I dumped the quality on that last line and no more error but, still no shadow which, is a real hair puller for me.

Comment: Then `$ibig` contains the error string `"Exception 410: unrecognized attribute `quality' @ Magick.xs/XS_Image__Magick_Montage/9797"`.  This means that the assignment to `$ibig` resulted in that error.  `quality` is indeed not an argument to `Montage()`.  See the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#exceptions) about exceptions.

Comment: Should I use $ibig = $ibig=>(yada) All the way down between resize and write? Thnaks for the assist.

Comment: No, see above documentation link to see which methods return a new image.

Comment: Read all docs for two days. However, you pointed me in the right direction and for that, I thank you. I used the $ibig = $ibig->Montage(...) then I dropped the whole last line before write and it worked! Thanks for your patience and assistance.